# Linq to XML: from query to variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I wrote this:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        string nodeName = "Mike";
        var query = from el in doc.Descendants("dogs")
                    where (string)el.Attribute("name") == nodeName
                    select
                    "Name: " + nodeName
                    + "\n" + "Breed: " + (string)el.Element("breed")
                    + "\n" + "Sex: " + (string)el.Element("sex");
        foreach (string data in query)
            MessageBox.Show(data);
```

Since I want to load this data, I want to put them into variables, to be able to put them later to textBoxes, radioBoxes, etc. For now I know only how to display it with MessageBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you are refering to this, but you can give it a try:

Make a new public class:

```
    public class XmlResut
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Breed { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; } // Maybe a enum would fit this property better
    }
```

Now you change the LINQ to create new instances of the defined class with a select new (http://www.dotnetperls.com/select-new)

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
    string nodeName = "Mike";
    var query = from el in doc.Descendants("dogs")
                where (string)el.Attribute("name") == nodeName
                select new XmlResult(){
                    Name = nodeName,
                    Breed = (string)el.Element("breed")
                    Sex = (string)el.Element("sex")
                };
    foreach (string data in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(data.Breed);
        Console.WriteLine(data.Sex);
    }
```

Comment: Why not serialize instead?

Comment: @ Ron Sijm: Not sure if PotatoBox would know about serialization, but you can make an answer to this question and explain it to him. I tried to keep it "simple".

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, but started from there and solved my problem, so it was helpful, thanks.

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can call [Enumerable.ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to store them in collection for later use.

```
var result = query.ToList();
foreach (string data in result)
        MessageBox.Show(data);

//result is available for later use
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I don't know if there's better way to achieve what I wanted, but it works.

```
    public class Data
    {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string breed { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    }
```

And method:

```
                  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"test.xml");
                  string nodeName = "Mike";
                  var data = from q in doc.Descendants("dogs")
                  where (string)q.Attribute("name") == nodeName
                      select new Data
                      {
                          name = q.Attribute("name").Value,
                          breed = q.Element("breed").Value,
                          sex = q.Element("sex").Value
                      };
                  foreach (var element in data)
                  {
                      textBox1.Text = element.name;
                      comboBox1.Text = element.sex;
                      textBox2.Text = element.breed;
                  }
```

Comment: Hm, I didn't realize that, but you're right. I guess I'll mark his answer as solution then.

Comment: At first I didn't really see a difference at all, the only thing different is that you are now using the correct .Value property (not all the time though). Btw, I hope you know that your textboxes/comboboxes will only hold the last found entry since you are always overriding .Text Property by enumerating threw the query.

Comment: You're right. I'll add another "where", that will contain "breed", since it's possible that two different dogs can have the same name, but different breed. I'll do that tomorrow and see if that works. Or maybe you know better method?